# OCServ to ask username and password in one page on Cisco Anyconnect

Tags: centos

I configured a ocserv server (OpenConnect) on CentOS 7.
when I want to connect to it with Cisco Anyconnect Client for iOS or Windows, username and password will be asked in 2 separated pages, how can I combine them in one page?

I read [this article](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mavrogiannopoulos-openconnect-02#section-2.1.2.1) , but I didn't found the XMLs to edit!

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This GitHub Repo I created should help worked for me.

https://github.com/thomaswilbur/OpenConnect-Auth-Hack

You will need two ports instead of one though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).